# VS2013 Project MS access and SQL server synchronization

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ms-access

I will try make this question clear as possible.
I have not found solid help on google really or anywhere else.

To make it short and simple.

I have a vb.net project in which i want two databases.

A local access database which must be created within the project at design, meaning at publishing and then installing this program to another user it must automatically create an acccess database on that user's computer,sync it with a SQL remote server and copy all records at first time run to the access database. The access database is used when my worker is on site and there is no connection to the remote SQL Server database.

Upon achieving connection to the remote SQL Server database at e.g. the office, the access db must update the SQL server database,compare the two databases and copy any new records in the local (Access Db) to the remote sql server and vice versa.

Hope this is clear enough?

Thanks for any help

Comment: A link to a solution would be great as i assume giving a solution as code in a comment might become lengthy

Comment: Okay i have found that local db cache has been removed from vs 2010 time already. No i guess it is time to find a full tutorial on sync framework which seems to be impossible as all links i find gives you datasheet and explanations on Sync Framework but no actual tutorial on how to do it. LINK TO A TUTORIAL ON SYNC FRAMEWORK PLEASE :)